# Why is the Positive cone (P) not equal to the ordered field (F)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ordered-fields

Given that a positive cone is
$$\forall x,y \in P, x+y \in P$$
$$\forall x,y \in P, xy \in P$$
$$\forall x \in F, \space \text{either} \space x \in P \space \text{or} -x \in P  \space \text{or} \space x=0$$
where we define $$b-a \in P \iff a<b \space \text{for some}\space a,b \space \text{in} \space F$$

I understand that for the order field of real numbers, the positive cone is $(0, +\infty)$ and clearly $\mathbb{R} = (0, +\infty)$ is false but I'm not sure that I understand how to express this formally.

Comment: Why there was a downvote with no comment? The question is reasonably phrased